# Cannot add foreign key constraint - MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql

I am aware that there are several other posts on this problem, but they normally have an apparent cause. I don't see what the problem is with my code.

I have tried:

- making sure ENGINE = INNODB.
- making sure the same datatype is used.
- removing code and only testing the tables where the error happens.

Below is the code. There are two tables, DESSERT and OFFER. I am creating two foreign keys in OFFER that correspond to the primary keys in DESSERT.

Important fact:

- I can comment away the second foreign key (corresponding to
  DESSERT_DATE), and the code will run. I have no problems creating the
  first foreign key.

Thanks for any help.

```
CREATE TABLE DESSERT (
DESSERT_CODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DESSERT_DATE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
DESSERT_DESCR VARCHAR(160),
DESSERT_NAME VARCHAR(10),
DRINK_NAME VARCHAR(26),
TOPPING_NAME VARCHAR(26),
DESSERT_PRICE_AMOUNT NUMERIC(6, 2),

PRIMARY KEY(DESSERT_DATE, DESSERT_CODE)
);


CREATE TABLE OFFER (
DESSERT_CODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DESSERT_DATE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
RESTAURANT_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY(DESSERT_CODE, DESSERT_DATE, RESTAURANT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (DESSERT_CODE) REFERENCES DESSERT(DESSERT_CODE),
FOREIGN KEY (DESSERT_DATE) REFERENCES DESSERT(DESSERT_DATE)
);
```

EDIT: So making the foreign key composite and changing the order did the trick.

Comment: database table already created or you need to create??

Comment: The DESSERT table is created. The OFFER can't be created because of the error.

Comment: ya its there bcz you cant create table(OFFER) without id or primary key

Comment: what are the fields comes in to offer table

Comment: answer is posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want separated foreign key, you need add unique key on DESSERT_CODE in DESSERT table.(But it may have totally different meaning)

This works:

```
CREATE TABLE DESSERT (
DESSERT_CODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DESSERT_DATE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
DESSERT_DESCR VARCHAR(160),
DESSERT_NAME VARCHAR(10),
DRINK_NAME VARCHAR(26),
TOPPING_NAME VARCHAR(26),
DESSERT_PRICE_AMOUNT NUMERIC(6 , 2 ),
PRIMARY KEY (DESSERT_DATE , DESSERT_CODE),
UNIQUE KEY (DESSERT_CODE)
);


CREATE TABLE OFFER (
DESSERT_CODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DESSERT_DATE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
RESTAURANT_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (DESSERT_CODE , DESSERT_DATE , RESTAURANT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (DESSERT_CODE)
    REFERENCES DESSERT (DESSERT_CODE),
FOREIGN KEY (DESSERT_DATE)
    REFERENCES DESSERT (DESSERT_DATE)
);
```

Or you need make sure you use both columns in your foreign key, as Misandrist already answered.

```
CREATE TABLE DESSERT (
DESSERT_CODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DESSERT_DATE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
DESSERT_DESCR VARCHAR(160),
DESSERT_NAME VARCHAR(10),
DRINK_NAME VARCHAR(26),
TOPPING_NAME VARCHAR(26),
DESSERT_PRICE_AMOUNT NUMERIC(6 , 2 ),
PRIMARY KEY (DESSERT_DATE , DESSERT_CODE)
);


CREATE TABLE OFFER (
DESSERT_CODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
DESSERT_DATE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
RESTAURANT_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (DESSERT_CODE , DESSERT_DATE , RESTAURANT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (DESSERT_DATE , DESSERT_CODE)
    REFERENCES DESSERT (DESSERT_DATE , DESSERT_CODE)
);
```

Comment: Could you explain why the order mattered in the composite foreign key?

Comment: Foreign key requires index where order of columns matters. A composite index is useless for searches on the second column, because sql doesn't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you really need is:

```
CREATE TABLE OFFER (
    DESSERT_CODE VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    DESSERT_DATE VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    RESTAURANT_ID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY(DESSERT_DATE, DESSERT_CODE, RESTAURANT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (DESSERT_DATE, DESSERT_CODE) REFERENCES DESSERT(DESSERT_DATE, DESSERT_CODE)
);
```

Since the primary key is composite, all foreign keys referencing it must also be composite.

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't do the trick. Besides, I can turn it into a single foreign key, i.e. removing DESSERT_DATE. The code will run. The error happens specifically when I try to make DESSERT_DATE a foreign key.

Comment: I edited the answer to have the same order for the keys. What error do you get specifically?

Comment: It only tells me "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint."

Comment: I tried what I think you meant. That is, write it as a composite foreign key and change the order of DESSERT_DATE and DESSERT_CODE. Does not work.

Comment: The above code works on my system.  Make sure you drop the OFFER table first, don't use CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST. If still not work, please post your full statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`DESSERT` (
  `DESSERT_CODE` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `DESSERT_DATE` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DESSERT_DESCR` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESSERT_NAME` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`DESSERT_CODE`, `DESSERT_DATE`))
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`OFFER` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `DESSERT_DESSERT_CODE` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `DESSERT_DESSERT_DATE` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_OFFER_DESSERT_idx` (`DESSERT_DESSERT_CODE` ASC, `DESSERT_DESSERT_DATE` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_OFFER_DESSERT`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DESSERT_DESSERT_CODE` , `DESSERT_DESSERT_DATE`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`DESSERT` (`DESSERT_CODE` , `DESSERT_DATE`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

`mydb` should be replace to your database name

Comment: Just create your database and run above code in **Query Window** with the modification.